# scala breeze compilation error

Tags: scala, compilation, scala-breeze

I am trying to compile the scala breeze library (release 0.9) with sbt 2.13.
I am getting the following error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\scala\breeze-releases-v0.9\project

[info] Set current project to breeze-parent (in build file:/C:/scala/breeze-releases-v0.9/)

[info] Compiling 280 Scala sources to C:\scala\breeze-releases-v0.9\math\target\scala-2.11\classes...

[error] C:\scala\breeze-releases-v0.9\math\src\main\scala\breeze\util\HeapDump.scala:5: object management is not a member of package com.sun

[error] import com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean

[error] C:\scala\breeze-releases-v0.9\math\src\main\scala\breeze\util\HeapDump.scala:21: not found: type HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean

[error]   private lazy val hotspotMBean: HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean = getHotspotMBean();

[error] C:\scala\breeze-releases-v0.9\math\src\main\scala\breeze\util\HeapDump.scala:38: not found: type HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean

[error]   private def getHotspotMBean():HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean = {

[error] C:\scala\breeze-releases-v0.9\math\src\main\scala\breeze\util\HeapDump.scala:42: not found: type HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean

[error]         HOTSPOT_BEAN_NAME, classOf[HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean]);

[error] four errors found
```

I am on java sdk 1.7.0_02

What should I do?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Can you see HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class inside the rt.jar for your java SDK? If the class or the com/sun/management path is missing, then you might need to use a different (i.e. Oracle, Sun or Open JDK) Java SDK.

Comment: If you can see the class, then perhaps your build file is not adding it to the classpath. If you include your SBT build file in your question then more SO users might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this on Breeze's mailing list, but this is because you're using a non-HotSpot VM. I'll delete this class in the next release of Breeze.